# How to import openssl generated certificate in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a certificate through openssl like this

```
Openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
```

Now i want to import this certificate into the client machine Java. How to import this certificate ?  Using keytool to import the certificate is right approach ?

Comment: Yes. See the JSSE Reference Guide and the `keytool` documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution ,as my virtual machine don't have DNS name so when generating certificate use command with IP-address if you have DNS name used that .

```
Openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=135.250.138.150/O=135.250.138.150"
```

Now in client machine use this command

```
keytool -import -file C:\Code_Base\Certificates\NGINX_150\tls.crt -storepass changeit -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\security\cacerts" alias 135.250.138.150
```

OR

```
keytool -import -file <Your .crt file location> -storepass changeit -keystore <Java cacerts file location> alias <Ip address of machine or DNS>
```

Comment: You've got no solution Subodh. You copy/paste answers from your other questions that you posted, and that  we stackoverflowers answered for you.You should clearly ask what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment